# How is continuity of a constant function defined?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

- Definition of continuity is that for small changes in the input there should be small changes in the output.Otherwise the function is discontinuous.

  So,with this definition we can say that a constant function is discontinuous.
- Another definition for continuity is that:
  "L.H.L = R.H.L = value of function at that point"

  with this definition we can say that constant function is continuous .

So,why am I facing a contradiction ,I wonder if my understanding is wrong about the continuity of a function.

Comment: No change is a small change 

Comment: [$\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit).

Comment: "No jumps, no gaps" is a good colloquial way to think of continuity.

Answer (score 3):

Your first definition is wrong. It should read:

> for small changes in the input there should **not** be large changes in the output. Otherwise the function is discontinuous.

No change is not a large change (which is what Cameron essentially said in jest in his comment).